# Prevent expand row on double click in w2ui grid table

Tags: grid, w2ui

Is it possible to avoid expand row on double click in w2ui grid?

And also i want to remove expand column (+ column) from div and i want on other column's click expand the row.
So should it possible or not?

I have tried to manually code to remove html code for expand column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onDblClick: function(event) {event.preventDefault(); }
```

this way expand will not triggered.